# A Database I made in MySQL Hosting is forming a table with empty data from an API made in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

So, I was able to make a connection an a database on MySQL Hosting using code straight from Visual Studio in JavaScript:

```js
const API = 'AIzaSy************************';
const client_id = '2585*************************************.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const client_secret = '5J**********************';
```

```js
function search(e) {
    e = url;
    var url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/?part=snippet&key=${API}&q=test&maxResults=20`;
    
    fetch(url).then(function(rep){

        return rep.json();

    }).then(function(data){

        console.log(data);
        show(data.items);

    })
}

console.log(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/?part=snippet&key=${API}&q=test&maxResults=20`);
```

```js
const https = require('https');
// const { createConnection } = require('net');
const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/?part=snippet&key=${API}&q=test&maxResults=20`;
https.get(url, res => {
  let data = '';
  res.on('data', chunk => {
    data += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    data = JSON.parse(data); // *IMPORTANT <-- This is where you will parse the data to the DB...
    console.log(data);
  })
}).on('error', err => {
  console.log(err.message);
})
```

```js
// import { createConnection } from 'mysql';
// const { createConnection } = require('net')
const mysql = require('mysql')

const con =  mysql.createConnection ({
    host: 'sql5.freemysqlhosting.net',
    user: 'sql*******',
    password: '**********Ti',
    database: 'sql******',
    port: '3306'
});



con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connect already!");
  var sql = `INSERT INTO YouTube_API_DB_Conn (kind, etag, id, snippet) VALUES (kind, etag, id, snippet)`
  con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Some record was inserted, hopefully, I don't freaking know....");
      console.log(result);

      /*
        con.query("SELECT * from ", function(err, result, fields) {
          if(err) throw err;
          console.log(result);
      }) 
      */
      console.log(sql)
  }); 
});
```

Now, the code in a functional sense (no errors are being made and nothing from the code breaks) works. My problem is that the table that is being created is being filled with empty data:

[Screenshot of query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be9Fn.png)

Does anyone have any pointers on how to fix this and have actually API data being inserted into the Database?

Comment: What do you mean by “MySQL Hosting”?

Comment: Also - you shouldn’t post your API keys and passwords in a public forum…

Comment: https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/

This place. It's an online, no need to install version of MySQL that I had to connect to through JavaScript.

Comment: I think you missed the block of code where you actually create the table.

Comment: Can you please share your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

The question looks incomplete. I am assuming u want to push the data by fetching from the api. 1. The api fetching will be done asynchronous, even before you fetch the data through api, the MySql thing will be executed. Make sure the flow is correct, please use console statements and try to print the content which you are trying to push to database.
Never post password, api key, client secret in the public forums.

Comment: Is doing this asynchronous the only way to get the data pulled from the API into a database on the server side?

Comment: Yes, that is the only way you can get response from server side. Your response must be inside the query execute block. You must return the response object after you get the database object.